# You have called the Google Maps API multiple times

Tags: reactjs, google-maps-api-3, clojurescript, reagent

I have a reagent component, and when it mounts I'm exporting a function called loadMap:

google_maps.js

```
export function loadMap() {
    // Create the script tag, set the appropriate attributes
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap';
    script.defer = true;
    script.async = true;

    // Attach your callback function to the `window` object
    window.initMap = function() {
        console.log("init map");
        console.log("Element is ", document.getElementById("map") )
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
            center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
            zoom: 8
        });
    };

    // Append the 'script' element to 'head'
    document.head.appendChild(script);

}
```

like so:

```
import loadMap from "google_maps.js"
```

The console is printing the logs of the callback function, but also shows the following:

```
You have included the Google Maps JavaScript API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.
cj @ js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap:138
ij @ js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap:135
google.maps.Load @ js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap:14
(anonymous) @ js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap:227
(anonymous) @ js?key=API_KEY&callback=initMap:227
```

and the map doesn't show.

-- EDIT --

The clojurescript import

```
        ["./google_maps.js" :refer (loadMap)]
```

```
(def load-map (with-meta identity
                {:component-did-mount
                 loadMap}))
```

Usage:

```
   [load-map
    [:div {:id "map"}]
    ]
```

Comment: How many requests for `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/` do you see in the network panel? Where do you execute loadMap() ?

Comment: It's reagent not react. Check the edit. I see the initMap console log twice.

Comment: Please don't share private API keys on public sites, and make sure you restrict them as per: https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices#restrict_apikey

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the `script` element inside of the `render()` method of a class-based component or inside the `return` statement of a functional component, then the script will be created as many times as your state updates.

In order to create the `script` element only once, either place it inside of the `onMount()` lifecycle method or employ the `useEffect()` hook.

You can pass your function into the `useEffect()` hook like so:

```
 import {useEffect} from "react"
 import loadMap from "google_maps.js";

 const App = () => {
    useEffect(loadMap, [])
    
    return (
        .....
        .....
        .....
    )
 }
```

This should only render your `script` element once when the component mounts. If you need to render it at another point in time, consider looking into other lifecycle methods and hooks.

Just be careful about having access to the `document`. React doesn't usually play nicely with direct access and maipulation like that. Might be better to try and use `refs` and render your elements using JSX rather than using the vanilla Javascript API.